# What devices have LDPI resolution with Android 2.2/2.3 version?

Tags: android, android-gui

What devices have LDPI(Low resolution) with Android 2.2\2.3 version?

Comment: Only LDPI I know is SE xperia mini / pro

Comment: The entry level Huawei Ideos has a small low density screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the complete list of Android Devices, just search and check resolutions: http://www.google.com/phone/#manufacturer=all&category=all&carrier=all&country=es&reset_filters=1

Comment: That list is not complete. There are other devices out there (e.g. Galaxy Tab 8.9 is not listed)

Comment: @MarvinLabs Galaxy Tab 8.9 was released October 2011 and this answer is older.

Answer (score -3):

Normally ldpi is ordinary screen, mdpi is 120, hdpi 240, 160, xhdpi is 320.
 I know also that Motorola's  small screen devices are low density.

Comment: Actually, android considers mdpi 160 the baseline. There are not a lot of device with ldpi.